# Where is the "Properties" or "Assemblyinfo.cs" file/folder

Tags: c#, visual-studio, properties

[image]

I hope this doesn't annoy anyone but I'm a complete noob at programming and just started 20 minutes ago. I'm watching a tutorial that's supposed to have a "Properties" folder with a file that is named "assemblyinfo.cs" inside of it and there isn't any. Help is appreciated!

There is an image above to help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You get that when you create a `.NET Framework` Console app.

[image: fig1]

But if you make a `.NET Core` Console app, there is no properties on the solution tree

[image: fig2]

You can still right click and select properties on the project object though.

You can also right click on the project and select `New Item..` and then `Assembly Information File`

[image: fig3]

This will create the `AssemblyInfo.cs` file you are looking for.

Comment: Hello this is really helpful but for some reason I can't create a project that has a .net framework all of them just say .net core in the description. The "Assembly information File" item is missing as well from the list. All this made me think that I might not have the .net framework installed but I went to the Microsoft website and downloaded .net framework 4.8 but it said that I already had it installed. Thanks for the help

Comment: @MrCalamari - [look for .NET Framework Console by filtering the new project](https://i.imgur.com/pm37t2G.png) page. Also you need to download the [.NET Framework Targeting Pack 4.8](https://dotnet.microsoft.com/download/dotnet-framework/net48)